# Binary Search Tree Shuffling and Resetting

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I was working on Binary Tree and want to figure out if is there any algorithm to shuffle the tree and to sort level wise?

Say for example I have an array as follows:

```
int[] values = new int[16] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
BinaryTree<int> tree = new BinaryTree<int>(values);
```

A constructor is already defined which creates a tree but now I need to create two functions which will shuffle and reset so are there algorithms I can read to implement?

Comment: can you provide more info about which language and which class represents your BinaryTree please?

Comment: What do you mean by "shuffle", "reset", and "sort level wise"?

Comment: it's C#. I got the figured out the algorithm myself. It's Fisher-Yates, I will post solution in some time.

Answer (score 2):

One can construct a random binary trees out of a set of values by using the following algorithm:

Input: values

1. randomly select a value as the root node - say r.
2. r->left = recursively build a random binary tree out of values[0..r].
3. r->right = recursively build a random binary tree out of values[r+1..values.length()-1].
4. return r.

Are you looking at shuffling the already created binary tree?

Comment: Yes the binary tree is created from integer values and once it's created I want to have a function to call to shuffle it randomly. I think I got the answer myself, just doing it right now.

Comment: This algorithm won't create a uniform distribution of possible binary trees as the lower index values will always end up in the left subtree (unless the root is 0).  Randomly choosing whether [0,r) is the left or right subtree is better, but still doesn't allow for r = 0 to not be a lop-sided tree.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the algo:

1. Create an array out of the binary tree.
2. Choose an element randomly from the list.
3. if root is not available, make the element choose as the root.
4. Select random value between 0 and 1 equally. If it's 0 element goes to left subtree. If it's 1 element goes to right subtree.
5. if left/right subtree is not present link the node with the current nodes left or right child. Else repeat step 4 until you reach to node where condition satisfies.

This will have uniform distribution.